# datyaq abort on ARM architecture

Tags: arm, abort

When I am using function name as variable mistakenly it is causing abort.

Condition is like this:

```
hello()
{
}

if(!hello) //this is crashing
{
}
```

As per my understanding this code should not crash as the function name is a valid address.
Also because of this my data segment is getting corrupted (not able to see any variable in crash inspect).